# Insert new child at the start of list in firebase document

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database structure like this:

[image]

Whenever a new object is added into the famuos_list, the list is displayed in Ascending order. 
Is there any way to insert the object such that the latest inserted object is always at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console always shows child nodes in lexicographic order, no matter how you added them.  If you need to impose a different ordering of child nodes, you should add some data to to each child that indicates its order, then [use that field in a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data) to retrieve them in that order.